# Printing only dates in MS Project 2010

Tags: printing, microsoft-project, microsoft-project-2010

Is it possible to print only the days, start and completion dates in MS Project, omitting the Gantt chart?

I'm trying to print all tasks on a neat single page, but the Gantt chart messes up the layout.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In MS Project 2007, this is possible by first changing the view to 'Task Sheet'.  To do this go to the View menu, click More Views..., choose 'Task Sheet'.  Now when you print it will omit the Gantt chart and legend at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Minimize the chart by dragging the split (between the table and the chart) to the right as much as possible until it is minimized completely.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using MS project 2010 above, you can save it as PDF format. then you can print with table without Gantt chart based on the page numbers. thanks.